Поиск строчки по файлам PyCharm
Всем привет, подскажите, можно ли искать конкретную переменную по всем файлам в проекте в PyCharm. Для поиска по конкретному файлу используется комбинация Ctrl+F, а можно ли использовать другую для поиска по всему проекту? Буду благодарен за ответ

Shift shift (два нажатия подряд)

Ctrl shift r тоже подойдёт

@Justiks для поиска без замены - Ctrl-Shift-F
